# Robust way to restrict file types that can be uploaded ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, validation, file-upload

We're working on an MVC app and we need to allow users to upload these file types:

DOC(X), XLS(X), PPT(X), Text, PDF, CSV, JPG and PNG.

All other file types must be prohibited.

Obviously, people can rename an executable file as a DOCX and upload it, so we do some rudimentary checks. For example, we check that the file doesn't start with the MZ byte signature, etc.

If they upload PNG or JPG, we check that they can be read using the .NET Bitmap class and that their dimensions fit within our parameters.

However, people are very clever (and devious). We need to have a robust solution that allows valid file types without letting executables, batch files, etc. to be uploaded.

For example, people can ZIP an EXE and try to upload it as a .DOCX file. Because DOCX files are zipped (and start with the PK signature), it gets tricky.

Furthermore, we don't want to install MS OFfice on our servers so using automation to test the uploads is not an option.

Short of reading up on all the binary specs for all the different file formats, what's the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Looks like this might do the job for me from a virus checking point of view: http://architectryan.com/2011/05/19/nclam-a-dotnet-library-to-virus-scan/#.Uu-4Rfl_t7E